# Joda Date Format Issue

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am trying to use the following code, but I am getting an error Invalid format: "12/11/2013":

```
String dFrom = ps.utils.gv(request, "dFrom");
String dTo = ps.utils.gv(request, "dTo");

DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(dFrom);
DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(dTo);

int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(dateFrom, dateTo).getWeeks();
```

Could somebody please provide an example of how to format the date variable dFrom which is typically a UK formatted date such as 12/11/2013 to an ISO Date such as 2013-11-12 which I believe Joda supports.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Do you want to parse (i.e. transform a String into a DateTime) or format (i.e. transform a DateTime into a String)? Have you read [the javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)? Reading documentation is an essential part of a programmer's job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want convert format `12/11/2013` to `2013-11-12`, you can use

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPatter("dd/MM/yyyy"); // or MM/dd/yyyy ?
String isoDate = ISODateTimeFormat.date().print(dtf.parseDateTime("12/11/2013"));
```

For ISO format `2013-11-12` you can use standart date formatter:
[ISODateTimeFormat::date()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#date%28%29)

```
DateTime date = ISODateTimeFormat.date().parseDateTime("2013-11-12"); 
String dateAsString = ISODateTimeFormat.date().print(date);
```

For format `12/11/2013` you should create your own formatter

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPatter("dd/MM/yyyy"); // or MM/dd/yyyy ?
DateTime date = dtf.parseDateTime("12/11/2013"); 
String dateAsString = dtf.print(date);
```